# stop node process that is running independently of the terminal session

Tags: node.js

This code spins up a node process independently of the terminal session:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// -*- mode: js -*-
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var opt = opt || {};

var stdout = opt.stdout || 'ignore';
var stderr = opt.stderr || 'ignore';

var env = opt.env || process.env;
var cwd = opt.cwd || process.cwd;

var cp_opt = {
  stdio: ['ignore', stdout, stderr],
  env: env,
  cwd: cwd,
  detached: true
};

var child = spawn(process.execPath, ['./bin/mock-server.js'], cp_opt);

// required so the parent can exit
child.unref();
```

Is there anyway I can stop this process?

Answer (score 0):

`child.kill()`  signal is `SIGTERM` by default.

Example:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const grep = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

grep.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(
    `child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}`);
});

// Send SIGHUP to process
grep.kill('SIGHUP'); //sends SIGHUP signal
```